# How to import vendor assets to webpacker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have added few javascript and css libraries to the vendor/stylesheets and vendor/javascript directories. I am not able to import those in my app/javascript/packs/application.js. I am using webpacker as my asset pipeline.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for your issue?

Comment: Can you please refer https://stackoverflow.com/q/61777360/936494 to see if it can of any help to provide guidance on resolving your problem?