# Rails 6 Webpacker calling javascript function from Rails view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I have following structure for Javascript in my Rails 6 app using Webpacker.

```
app/javascript
  + packs
    - application.js
  + custom
    - hello.js
```

Below shown is the content in the above mentioned JS files

**app/javascript/custom/hello.js**

```
  export function greet(name) {
    console.log("Hello, " + name);
  }
```

**app/javascript/packs/application.js**

```
  require("@rails/ujs").start()
  require("jquery")
  require("bootstrap")

  import greet from '../custom/hello'
```

**config/webpack/environment.js**

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

Now in my Rails view I am trying to use the imported function `greet` like shown below

**app/views/welcome/index.html.haml**

```
  - name = 'Jignesh'

  :javascript

    var name = "#{name}"
    greet(name)
```

When I load the view I am seeing `ReferenceError: greet is not defined` error in browser's console.

I tried to search for a solution to this problem and found many resources on web but none turned out to help me. At last when I was drafting this question in the suggestions I found [How to execute custom javascript functions in Rails 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59349091/how-to-execute-custom-javascript-functions-in-rails-6) which indeed is close to my need **however the solution shows a workaround but I am looking for a proper solution** for the need because I have many views which needs to pass data from Rails view to JS functions to be moved custom files under `app/javascript/custom` folder.

Also I would highly appreciate if anybody can help me understand the cause behind the `ReferenceError` I am encountering.

**Note**:

I am not well-versed in Javascript development in Node realm and also new to Webpacker, Webpack, Javascript's modules, `import`, `export`, `require` syntax etc so please bear with me if you find anything silly in what I am asking. I have landed up in above situation while trying to upgrade an existing Rails app to use version 6.

Answer (score 4):

Webpack does not make modules available to the global scope by default. That said, there are a few ways for you to pass information from Ruby to JavaScript outside of an AJAX request:

1. `window.greet = function() { ... }` and calling the function from the view as you have suggested is an option. I don't like have to code side effects in a lot of places so it's my least favorite.
2. You could look at using [`expose-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/expose-loader/). This would mean customizing your webpack config to "expose" selected functions from selected modules to the global scope. It could work well for a handful of cases but would get tedious for many use cases.
3. Export selected functions from your entrypoint(s) and configure webpack to package [your bundle as a library](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytarget). This is my favorite approach if you prefer to call global functions from the view. [I've written about this approach specifically for Webpacker on my blog](https://rossta.net/blog/from-sprockets-to-webpack.html#exporting-from-webpack).

   ```js
   // app/javascript/packs/application.js

   export * from '../myGlobalFunctions'


   // config/webpack/environment.js

   environment.config.merge({
     output: {
       // Makes exports from entry packs available to global scope, e.g.
       // Packs.application.myFunction
       library: ['Packs', '[name]'],
       libraryTarget: 'var'
     },
   })
   ```

   ```
   // app/views/welcome/index.html.haml

   :javascript
     Packs.application.greet("#{name}")
   ```
4. Take a different approach altogether and attach Ruby variables to a global object in your controller, such as with the [`gon` gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon). Assuming you setup the gem per the instructions, the `gon` object would be available both as Ruby object which you can mutate server-side and in your JavaScript code as a global variable to read from. You might need to come up with some other way to selectively call the greet function, such as with a DOM query for a particular selector that's only rendered on the given page or for a given url.

   ```rb
   # welcome_controller.rb

   def index
     gon.name = 'My name'
   end
   ```

   ```js
   // app/javascript/someInitializer.js

   window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     if (window.location.match(/posts/)) {
       greet(window.gon.name)
     }
   })
   ```

Answer (score 2):

**@rossta Thanks a lot for your elaborate answer. It definitely should be hihghly helpful to the viewers of this post**.

Your 1st suggestion I found while searching for solution to my problem and I did referenced it in my question. Like you I also don't like it because it is sort of a workaround.

Your 2nd and 3rd suggestions, honestly speaking went top of my head perhaps  because I am novice to the concepts of Webpack.

Your 4th approach sounds more practical to me and as a matter of fact, after posting my question yesterday, along similar lines I tried out something and which did worked. I am sharing the solution below for reference

**app/javascript/custom/hello.js**

```
  function greet(name) {
    console.log("Hello, " + name)
  }

  export { greet }
```

**app/javascript/packs/application.js**

```
  require("@rails/ujs").start()
  require("bootstrap")
```

**Note that in above file I removed `require("jquery")`. That's because it has already been made globally available in `/config/webpack/environment.js` through `ProvidePlugin` (please refer the code in my question). Thus requiring them in this file is not needed. I found this out while going through 
"Option 4: Adding Javascript to environment.js" in http://blog.blackninjadojo.com/ruby/rails/2019/03/01/webpack-webpacker-and-modules-oh-my-how-to-add-javascript-to-ruby-on-rails.html**

**app/views/welcome/index.html.haml**

```
  - first_name = 'Jignesh'
  - last_name = 'Gohel'

  = hidden_field_tag('name', nil, "data": { firstName: first_name, lastName: last_name }.to_json)
```

**Note: The idea for "data" attribute got from https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/props.md**

**app/javascript/custom/welcome_page.js**

```
  import { greet } from './hello'

  function nameField() {
    return $('#name')
  }

  function greetUser() {
    var nameData = nameField().attr('data')

    //console.log(nameData)
    //console.log(typeof(nameData))

    var nameJson = $.parseJSON(nameData)

    var name = nameJson.firstName + nameJson.lastName

    greet(name)
  }

  export { greetUser }
```

**app/javascript/packs/welcome.js**

```
  import { greetUser } from '../custom/welcome_page'

  greetUser()
```

Note: The idea for a separate pack I found while going through https://blog.capsens.eu/how-to-write-javascript-in-rails-6-webpacker-yarn-and-sprockets-cdf990387463
under section "Do not try to use Webpack as you would use Sprockets!" (quoting the paragraph for quick view)

> So how would you make a button trigger a JS action? From a pack, you add a behavior to an HTML element. You can do that using vanilla JS, JQuery, StimulusJS, you name it.

Also the information in https://prathamesh.tech/2019/09/24/mastering-packs-in-webpacker/ helped in guiding me to solve my problem.

Then updated **app/views/welcome/index.html.haml** by adding following at the bottom

```
= javascript_pack_tag("welcome")
```

Finally reloaded the page and the webpacker compiled all the packs and I could see the greeting in console with the name in the view.

I hope this helps someone having a similar need like mine.

Comment: I support the idea of using data attributes and reading from the DOM too; I could’ve included that as a 5th item on my list.